# python - what does n += 2 in this def?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does += mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823561/what-does-mean-in-python)

I have a def function looks like:

```
def s(xs, n, m):
    t = []
    while n < m:
        t.append(xs[n])
        n += 2
    return t
```

I understand the above code by t.append(xs[n]), but have no idea what n += 2 means here.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It's equivalent to n = n + 2; specifically, the function returns an array with every other element of the inputted array starting at the initial index n and going until index m.

Comment: Read the docs. http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements

Answer (score 2):

It adds 2 to n. And I need 30 characters for an answer.