# What does "^=" mean in Python?

Tags: python, operators

## What does `^=` do in python?

I'm uncertain of whether `^` and `^=` are similar or related in their name or behavior.

### Example question:

Given a non-empty array of integers, every element appears twice except for one. Find that single one.

`nums = [3,3,4,2,2]`

```py
def singleNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        a = 0
        for i in nums:
            a ^= i
        return a
```

I expect the output to be `4` in this case. But I have yet to find any definitive resource explaining how the `^=` operator works.

Please explain what it is & how it works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451386, it's also listed with the other operators [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations).

Comment: `a ^= i` is equivalent to `a = a ^ i`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the caret operator (^) in Python do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451386/what-does-the-caret-operator-in-python-do)

Comment: That seem to be leetcode problem?

Comment: I'd suggest leaving this question as there is substantial precedence for not merging questions about these types of operators into the base operator questions.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823561/what-does-mean-in-python/823878

Answer (score 3):

The ^ operator is a binary XOR (exclusive OR).  So ^= is an XOR of i over a, placed back in a.

for example:

```
a  = 9 1001
a ^= 5 0101
       ----
   XOR 1100 = 12

a will contain 12
```

For the list [3,3,4,2,2]:

```
a  = 0 000
a ^= 3 011 -> 011
a ^= 3        011 -> 000
a ^= 4               100 -> 100
a ^= 2                      010 -> 110
a ^= 2                             010 -> 100 = 4
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in how the algorithm actually works, it depends on the unwanted elements to be pairs - specifically an even number of them. Using XOR, you can do things like:

```
>>> A ^ A
 0
>>> B == A ^ B ^ A
 True
```

for any integer values of A and B. I.e. an XOR of something with itself is zero, `A ^ A` is zero. Similarly a number XOR zero is itself, like  `A ^ 0` is `A`. The operation is also commutative, so `A ^ A ^ B` (which reduces to `0 ^ B` which is simply B) is the same as `A ^ B ^ A`. So if you apply this to a list where all but one element appears an even number of times, the only the odd one out remains when they are all XOR'd together.

As for the `^=` operator, that is explained already. `A ^= B` is the same as `A = A ^ B`. Many operators can be used this way, e.g. `A += 1` is the same as `A = A + 1`.